# Import plain text into a MATLAB matrix as numbers for semantic neural net analysis

Tags: matlab, matrix, text, text-classification, converters

It seems one must employ a script to import plain text into MATLAB, convert it to numerical format, and store it in a matrix. This step is required for any sort of analysis of the text data in MATLAB, such as extraction of semantic features using neural networks or classifying texts for known features, for instance. I did not find any way to do it without scripting. Here's what I wrote:

```
%texttoconvertincellarray- is a cell array where each row has text data imported from a csv file

longestrow=texttoconvertincellarray(cellfun(@(x) numel(x),texttoconvertincellarray)==max(cellfun(@(x) numel(x),texttoconvertincellarray))); %find the longest string in cell array rows
maxrowsize=cellfun('length',longestrow); %get longest string size to set max matrix Y
A=zeros(maxrowsize,length(texttoconvertincellarray)); %create an empty matrix the size of data
                                                      %Y - rows of imported cell array
                                                      %X - size of the longest string in rows
                                                      %later will transpose the matrix
j=1; %matrix element sequential index
for i=1:length(texttoconvertincellarray)              %loop through each row of text data imported 
                                                      %into cell array
    conv = double(texttoconvertincellarray{i});       %convert characters of each row of the cell 
                                                      %array to integer code representations
    A(j:j+length(conv)-1) = conv;                     %update matrix element range starting at each 
                                                      %column's first element with the converted data
    j=j+size(A,1);                                    %increment matrix element sequential index to 
                                                      %the next column's first element
end
A=transpose(A); %transpose the matrix; this is necessary because matrix sequential element addressing works verically, then horizontally

%now each row in matrix A represents sentences in the imported cell array, with letters converted to 
%numerical representations
```

Can this be streamlined further, if not for anything else then for elegance?

Comment: You can stil import some data into tables using "Import data" button available on the main interface (command window). While importing, select the type of data you want with the drop down menu on the column head. I would choose "string", and then if necessary convert this string information to double. But you can do plenty of stuff with the String class.

Comment: Is there a benefit of importing strings into a table vs cell array?

Comment: See Table vs. Cells here:  https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/advantages-of-using-tables.html. And Strings is the format used in the Text Analytics Toolbox.